# PHP Display Magento Yes/No Attribut if Value is Yes and display an jpg instead of "yes"

Tags: php, magento

I would like to display Yes/No Attributes in my view.phtml. I tried some codes but none is working.

Firstly I tried this syntax, which I found only and which is working for Attributes with Text-Values:

```
<?php 
  if ($_product->getAn_342() != null && $_product->getAn_342() != "") {
    echo $this->__('Deliveryinformation'); 
    echo  $_product->getAn_342(); 
  } 
?>
```

This does not work for Attributes with yes/no Values. With this syntax there is displayed the Magento-ID of the Attribut but not the Value.

Next I tried this Syntax, which I found here in this forum:

```
<?php 
      if ($_product->getAttributeText($_data['An_56']) == "Yes"): 
 ?>
```

But this does not work as well.

For explanation:
One Attribut i want to display would be "Bestseller". The Attribut has Label "**an_bestsller**" and code "**an_56**", which will be the **magento-Id**.

So what exactly is wrong with that yes/no syntax above? Some help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do as follows :

```
$attr = $product->getResource()->getAttribute("oversize_type");
if ($attr->usesSource()) {
    $oversizeLabel = $attr->getSource()->getOptionText($oversizeId);
}
```

Please change oversize_type to your attribute code

Above is the way of getting the option text of dropdown type.

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You've to check different translatable values: 'N/A' or 'NO':

```
if ($_product->getAttributeText($_data['An_56']) =! $this->__("N/A") && $_product->getAttributeText($_data['An_56'] != $this->__('NO')):
```

It is better to make an extension which extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Attributes and overwrites the function getAdditionalData:

```
public function getAdditionalData(array $excludeAttr = array())
{
    $data = parent::getAdditionalData($excludeAttr);

    foreach ($data as $code => $item) {
        if ($item['value'] == Mage::helper('catalog')->__('N/A')
            || $item['value'] == Mage::helper('catalog')->__('No')

            //You can add more values to hide
            //|| $item['value'] == Mage::helper('catalog')->__('--')
        ) {
            unset($data[$code]);
        }
    }

    return $data;
}
```